# Add a user on a remote computer with authentication

Tags: vbscript, remote-access

I am trying to write a VBScript to connect to a computer remotely and then add a user there on the remote machine.

I looked up on the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) website and used the following code to connect to the remote computer.

```
strComputer = "192.168.0.3"
Set objSWbemLocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
Set objSWbemServices = objSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(strComputer, "root\cimv2", "username", "password")
objSWbemServices.Security_.ImpersonationLevel = 3
```

But on execution, it shows an error that RPC server is unavailable.

Please help me resolve it, and also let me know how to proceed to adding user after that.

Comment: I don't think this is a programming issue; it seems more like a system administration issue.  Is RPC configured correctly on the remote machine?   You should put some research into that, or possibly ask your question on http://superuser.com/

Comment: remoteprocedurecall service on the remote system should be running to accept these requests. check for the service and start it

Comment: @SreeHarsha It's more likely that the Windows Firewall is blocking the connection attempts.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers : Good point. let us see what the user has to say.
in our company we disable windows firewall on all the machines as they are already in a corporate network and have additional security applications